# The embeddings of GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin is stemmed or not?

Tags: word-embeddings

I will use the embedding GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin data to do some project. Just want to know whether it was stemmed of the words?

Answer (score 1):

No - the tokens in GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin are not stemmed. Looking at the [documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/), example tokens include:

- "argue"
- "argues"
- "arguing"
- "argument"
- "arguments"